# C# WPF animations from separate threads

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, animation

I have trouble with animations. I have to control my double animation from asynchronous threads. Seperate threads will change uklepe value asynchronously, animations will play as a result of changes. That's what i tried but i am still getting this error even i used Dispatcher :

> The Calling Thread Cannot Access This Object Because A Different Thread Owns It

```
    protected bool üstklepe = false;
    public bool uklepe
    {
        get
        {
            return üstklepe;
        }
        set
        {
            if (üstklepe == false && value == true)
            {
                var da = new DoubleAnimation(0, 90, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100)));
                var rt = new RotateTransform(0, 0, 0);
               Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {Ustklepe.RenderTransform = rt;});
                Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {Ustklepe.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0, 0);});
                 Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {rt.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, da);});

                RadialGradientBrush myBrush = new RadialGradientBrush();
                myBrush.GradientOrigin = new Point(0.35, 0.65);
                myBrush.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.White, 0.0));
                myBrush.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FF91D393"), 0.916));

                //SolidColorBrush Brush = new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FF91D393"));
                Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { Ustklepe.Fill = myBrush; });



                üstklepe = value;

            }
            else if (üstklepe == true && value == false)
            {
                var da = new DoubleAnimation(90, 0, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100)));
                var rt = new RotateTransform(0, 0, 0);
                 Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {Ustklepe.RenderTransform = rt;});
                 Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {Ustklepe.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0, 0);});
                 Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {rt.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, da);});


                RadialGradientBrush myBrush = new RadialGradientBrush();
                myBrush.GradientOrigin = new Point(0.35, 0.65);
                myBrush.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.White, 0.0));
                myBrush.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FFFF2F33"), 0.916));

                //SolidColorBrush Brush = new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FFFF2F33"));
                Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { Ustklepe.Fill = myBrush; });



                üstklepe = value;

            }
            else
                üstklepe = value;

        }
    }
```

Comment: sorry, i put wrongly . now edited. thats the final version of my code but i am still getting this error from here: Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {rt.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, da);});

Comment: All objects derived from DispatcherObject must be be created in the same thread.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is even though you are setting the rotate transform with dispatcher you are creating the instance in the thread which sets the uklepe property with these lines.

```
        var da = new DoubleAnimation(0, 90, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100)));
        var rt = new RotateTransform(0, 0, 0);
```

Edit: And these lines too

```
        RadialGradientBrush myBrush = new RadialGradientBrush();
        myBrush.GradientOrigin = new Point(0.35, 0.65);
        myBrush.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.White, 0.0));
        myBrush.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FFFF2F33"), 0.916));
```

You need to run these lines inside the UI thread too

Comment: The animation itself could be a problem but the brush definitely will be.

Comment: Yeah I didn't see that it should be created on the UI thread too.